# Ubuntu unable to automatically mount the disk

Tags: mount, automount

I have recently bought an external hard disk. However, when I plugged it into my computer, ubuntu fails to automatically mount it. I have to manually do it using terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/external_disk -t ntfs-3g
```

Is this an issue with ubuntu 14.04 mounting NTFS? How to fix this issue? Is it related to the following error that I got when mounting the disk?

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
```

Also, I cannot see it in the partitioning software `Disks` to change the format, or in the shortcuts menu, etc. Is there a workaround to this?

Something that seemed strange to me is the permissions on the devices:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 10 13:43 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Apr 10 13:43 /dev/sdb1
brw------- 1 root root 8, 32 Apr 10 13:43 /dev/sdc
brw------- 1 root root 8, 33 Apr 10 16:02 /dev/sdc1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry to the /etc/fstab file to have the partition mount automatically.  Use sudo on the blkid command:

```
sudo blkid
```

To find the UUID of sdc1, and follow the existing columns to add the new line.  something like

```
UUID=<your uuid>  /mnt/external_disk ntfs user,auto,nosuid,rw 0 0
```

---

The existing mount point, /mnt/external_disk should be owned by root and root group, with permissions of 755.

Comment: The problem is that `blkid` takes a long time to print the UUID (it hasn't shown anything yet). Does it meant that there is a problem with HDD? Then why the HDD is mounted and works?

Comment: Could this be caused by the permissions? I am not sure if it's safe to change the permission and owner.